# Property from base class may not be public in child class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have a child class that inherits from a parent class. This parent class has a property Id. In my child class I want to give that the property Id and change the parents Id property to a different name in my child class.

```
Public Class Product ' This is the base class
    Private _iId As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer ' This is the Id from the product
        Get
            Return _iId
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class OrderProduct ' This is the child class
    Inherits Product

    Private _iId As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer ' This has to be the Id of the Order
        Get
            Return _iId
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _iIdProduct As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property IdProduct As Integer ' This has to be the Id of the Product
        Get
            Return ? ? ?
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: title doesnt seem to match the question. it looks like _iId on the parent and _iIdProduct on the child class duplicate each other.  Get rid of the second, define `_iId` as Friend, then return `MyBase._iId` on the child class.  OR return `MyBase.Id` and get rid of the second backing field.  you have a lot of duplication and options.  Product.ID and OrderProduct.ID make it confusing.  COnsider `ProductID` and `OrderId` as property names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class Product
  Protected iID As Int32 = -1
  Public Readonly Property ID As Int32
    Get
      Return iID
    End Get
  End Property
End Class


Public Class OrderProduct
  Inherits Product

  Protected  iID As Int32 = -1
  Public Shadows Readonly Property ID As Int32
    Get
      Return iID
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Readonly Property ProductID As Int32
    Get
      Return MyBase.ID
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

**This is a really bad idea.**  This would be a definite abuse of inheritance.  Rather consider encapsulation, where your OrderProduct has a property for both the Product and the Order.  Or make your Order class contain both a `ProductID` and an `OrderID`.

Redefining the ID in your derived class is a really bad idea.

Comment: The Id (of the product) and the Id (of the orderproduct) are 2 different Id's. I just want to rename the Id (of the product to ProductId) so the Id (of the OrderProduct) is Id